# how to set ASP.NET version for virtual directory using .net

Tags: c#, .net, iis, virtual-directory

how to set ASP.NET version for virtual directory using c#.net FROM CODE for all iis version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the folllowing code worked out for me
            string physicalPath ="D:\SVN\Safetypad\SafetyPADUniversal";
            System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.IISVirtualRoot vr = new System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.IISVirtualRoot();

```
        string sError = "";

        string VDName = "MY";

        vr.Create("IIS://localhost/W3SVC/1/Root", physicalPath, VDName, out sError);


        if (sError.Trim().Length > 0)
            throw new Exception("Error when creating Virtual Directory:" + Environment.NewLine + sError);

        DirectoryEntry deVDir = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://localhost/W3SVC/1/Root/" + VDName);
        deVDir.Properties["Path"].Value = physicalPath;

        deVDir.Properties["DefaultDoc"].Value = "Mainscreen1.aspx";
        foreach (PropertyValueCollection val in deVDir.Properties)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(val.PropertyName);
        }


        PropertyValueCollection vals = deVDir.Properties["ScriptMaps"];
        ArrayList objScriptMaps = new ArrayList();

                  objScriptMaps.Add(val.Replace(version,frameworkVersion));



        string _frameWorkDir;
        string _Dir;
        string _FrameWorkVersion = "2.0.50727";
        _Dir = System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeEnvironment.GetRuntimeDirectory();
        int dirpos = _Dir.Remove(_Dir.Length - 1, 1).LastIndexOf(@"\");
        _frameWorkDir = _Dir.Remove(dirpos, _Dir.Length - dirpos);
        _frameWorkDir = _frameWorkDir + @"\v" + _FrameWorkVersion + @"\";

        Process pro = new Process();
        pro.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        pro.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        pro.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        pro.StartInfo.FileName = _frameWorkDir + "aspnet_regiis";
       pro.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-s " + @"/W3SVC/1/Root/";

        pro.Start();
        pro.WaitForExit();
```